# How to access this array to render elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

im having a kind of an array as result of a calcaulation which looks something like this:

```
{"5":3,"12":4,"3":12}
```

I need to have the keys and values seperate to render html elements. This is what I have so far:

```
  Object.entries(doubleNumbers).map(
    ([key, value]) => <li>{doubleNumbers[key]} {doubleNumbers[value]}</li>
))
```

Well im only getting 3,4,12 as result.. Something is missing/wrong.

Comment: The key is the actual key which you can print. Now you are calling the value in doubleNumbers[key]. You can just put {key}.

Comment: No need to use doubleNumbers in the <li> tag any more. Just use key and value there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you were referencing `doubleNumners[key]` etc, but here is how to access the variables in the map you started

```js
let doubleNumbers = {"5":3,"12":4,"3":12}

let li =  Object.entries(doubleNumbers).map(
    ([key, value]) => `<li>${key} :  ${value}</li>`
)

document.getElementById('n').innerHTML = li.join("")
```

```html
<ul id='n'></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for in loop. This could help you.

```js
var data = {"5":3,"12":4,"3":12};

for (const d in data) {
  console.log(d, data[d]);
}
```